# How to label by date of file in Visual SourceSafe?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, label

I would like to label a project and its files in VSS according to a certain previous date. In other words, I would like to be able to select versions of each file in a project as they existed on a particular date and then apply the label to those versions of the files. I have tried pinning files and then labelling the project (and its files), but that failed. This is a very simple task in ClearCase. Is there no simple way to do this in VSS?

Answer (score 0):

The pinning and labeling should work, however due to a display bug where things are displayed in order of date instead of the actual revision number order the label will look like it is associated to the newest revision of the file at the time the label was placed.

You can verify the actual revision a label is associated with a few ways, from the GUI you can select the label and do a diff with the newest version, since it is associated with a different version you should see that the label and the revision right below it do not match and indeed differences exist.

An alternative way to check it is to "pin" at the label.  Select the label and pin the file, a pin will show up on the proper revision actually associated with the label.

Finally you can use the command line and do a ss dir -vl"" which will display the actual version of the label, combine this with ss dir -vd"" and you should see that your label and the date revisions are in sync.

Best of luck.